# laravel put html select dropdown "selected" at two data

Tags: laravel, dropdown, html-select

I've check the data based on user details to auto selected the list from dropdown like below

```
<option {{ $user->grade == "10" ? 'selected' : '' }} value="10">10</option>
<option {{ $user->grade == "10 (A)" ? 'selected' : '' }} value="10 (A)">10 (A)</option>
```

please notice that `space` is there in `10 (A)`

But in the form (page) both of them are putting `selected` (the user grade is `10`)

[image]

how to avoid this things. Data type of grade is `string`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried with `===`?

Comment: yes, nothing is `selected`

Comment: Also you should use `blade` if directive here because it looks nicer. Like this `@if($user->grade == '10') selected @endif`

Comment: let me try `if ()`

Comment: @junaidrasheed the result is same (like my question)

Comment: I guess it is not `String` it is `Integer` check with `gettype($user->grade)` ?

Comment: Why don't you try it with if else statements instead of conditional operator?

Comment: I recreated the above scenario with the exact same options and it worked for me (Using @if blade directives) . You need to make sure that the `$user->grade` is returning what you expect.

Comment: Use type casting like this : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7bbbe5c1762a79b41ea32a05b61b86dc9fa4c093

Comment: Yes, the data-type is `integer` it's used from another table.. sorry for my mistake, but in `grade table` I used as string...

Comment: use === and YODA for strict checking. else, it may fail for 10 in case of 10 and 10 (A)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `$user->grade` in not a `string` variable. You can cast your variable to `string` and then compare it

```
<option {{ (string)$user->grade == "10" ? 'selected' : '' }} value="10">10</option>
<option {{ (string)$user->grade == "10 (A)" ? 'selected' : '' }} value="10 (A)">10 (A)</option>
```

[PHP -> Type Casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)